# Unable to print generated landscape pdf correctly to printer

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-fop

I'm been using the Apache fop xsl-fo convertor to pdf for printing purpose, however when I try to print a landscape pdf, the printing mechanism tried to turn the landscape pdf into portrait and print in portrait.

I had also tried to print via pdfbox, and it is not working also.

So my question is, am I able to explicitly specify the page orientation before printing and prevent the printing mechanism to turn the landscape pdf into portrait before printing.

Code:

```
ExampleFO2JPSPrint pjs = new ExampleFO2JPSPrint();
pjs.printFOOldStyle(PathUtility.getInstance().getFileByPath("cache/cache.xsl"),
                    printService);

FO2PDF obj = new FO2PDF();
obj.main(PathUtility.getInstance().getFileByPath("cache/cache.xsl"),
         PathUtility.getInstance().getFileByPath("out/ResultFO2PDF.pdf"));
```

[Generated pdf file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30651396069273381607)

This piece of code is able to generate the correct pdf orientation, but the problem is this printing code.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(
                PathUtility.getInstance().getFileByPath("out/ResultFO2PDF.pdf"));

//doc.print(pj); 
//doc.silentPrint(pj);
pj.defaultPage();
pj.setCopies(1);
pj.setPrintService(printService);                  
pj.setPageable(doc);
pj.print();

doc.close();
```

which generated the following print pdf. It looks fine if I send it to a A4 printer, which I'm not sending to, and the printer that I send to doesn't recognize the orientation and prints in portrait mode instead, so the text is in the wrong orientation.

Is there a way to specify the orientation of the print file before sending to the printjob?

[Printed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ii7.jpg)

Comment: I've never had any problem doing this.  Does the file look correct when you view it with the PDF reader of your choice?

Comment: You should post the source code that you used. And a link to the file, if it isn't confidential.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for responding, i had edited my post. @TilmanHausherr

Comment: @DavidWallace, yes the generated pdf file look correctly, but the print outcome detect the orientation correctly, nt sure whether is it the paper size ? my paper size is 9cm x 7cm.

Comment: What is the type of the `pj` variable?  And are you sure your paper is 9cm x 7cm?  That seems very small to me - I've never heard of this paper size.

Comment: pj class type is PrinterJob

yes it is 9cm x 7cm, it is a barcode printer. i think thats the reason why the orientation go haywire.

i found a piece of code that can manually turn the document before printing, but the code is not so prefer as i want the application to be able to work across multiple range of printer also.

the code that can bypass this problem can be found here

[link](http://pk345.blogspot.sg/2012/11/pdfbox-landscape-printing-problem-and.html) @DavidWallace

Comment: Your "Generated pdf file" is a jpg link

Comment: sorry, i had updated the link @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I looked into the source code of the 1.8 version of PDFBox. It uses landscape if media width >= media height. The best would be that you download the source code with svn and modify that part. It is in the file PDPageable.java. More details here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#scm
get the 1.8 branch, not the trunk. The trunk has partly a different API.

Comment: I also looked into the source code of the 2.0 version of PDFBox. This one allows to set the orientation to portrait, landscape or auto (you don't want auto, obviously :-) ). You can get it from svn or from 
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/
It has a different API, so you should still get the source code to see the examples.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks alot man!, btw i can't find the source code for the version 2.0.
[http](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/)

just one final question, i managed to download the src of 1.8.5, and compile my own jar file, however the jar file i compile is not the standalone-jar. which their provide over here [link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, sorry i found the 2.0 source code, is in the trunk.., however.. for that final question, how to i compile an standalone pdfbox-app.jar?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, its okay now, i solved the orientation issues using the 2.0 version. thanks!